# Laptop does not hibernate when power levels get critical

Tags: windows-10, battery, hibernate

I have been having issues where when i close the lid on my laptop when i go to bed at night, it always has drained the power completely during the night. So i lose all my chrome tabs, word documents and etc. when i open it in the morning. Shouldn't the laptop stop the battery from draining by hibernating after some time? And i know it has the function to hibernate when the battery gets critically low, but it seems to not shut down instead. Has been getting seriously annoying now, really :)

Model: ASUS ROG GL552VW

OS: Windows 10 (came with windows 8, but updated some time ago)

Comment: have you checked the power settings? Make sure critical battery action is enabled and set to hibernate. If critical battery level is less than 7%, try changing it to 10%

Comment: @Blaine The critical battery level is at 7%, battery reserve level 8% and the critical battery action is set to hibernate

Comment: you could try increasing it to something like 15% just to see if that solves it